# linq join many-many relationship table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, many-to-many

I have 3 entities App, User, Group. they all have many-many relationship. They have the following attributes

```
App: AppID, AppName
Group: GroupID, GroupName
User: UserID, UserName
```

I want to get a list of apps of a certain user. For exp: 'Thor' is in 'The Avengers' group. The 'Avenger Group' have access to these apps 'Flying', 'Super Power', 'Lightning Strike', etc.

First, I'd join 'User' table and 'Group' table to get which group 'Thor' is in ('The Avenger' group). Then joining 'Group' table and 'App' table to know which apps the group 'The Avenger' have access to. Then I will get the list of apps for user 'Thor'

my current linq query return all apps (not apps of user 'Thor')

This is the linq query

```
AppListViewModel apps = new AppListViewModel {
                Apps = from u in User
                               from g in u.Group
                               from a in g.App
                               where u.UserName=="Thor"
                               select new AppDTO {
                                   AppID=a.AppID,
                                   AppName=a.AppName,

                               },
};
```

Comment: And what are you looking to do?

Comment: my current query return all apps. but i only wants apps that user'Thor' have access to

Answer (score 0):

Why not use joins:

```
from u in User
join g in u.Group on u.GroupID equals g.GroupID
from a in g.App on g.AppID equals a.AppID
where u.UserName=="Thor"
select new AppDTO {
    AppID=a.AppID,
    AppName=a.AppName,
},
```

That should do the proper filtering.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var apps = (
   from u in User
   from g in u.Group
   from a in g.App
   where u.UserName == "Thor"
   select new AppDTO { AppID = a.AppID, AppName = a.AppName }
).ToList();
```